# Редактор для сайта на js

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Написал движок википедии ( http://centerix.ru/wiki/ ), для полного счастья не хватает нормального редактора. Сейчас, при нажатии кнопки, текст посылается на сервер, обрабатывается древним джижком на c++ и выдается пользователю в виде html кода.

Подскажите движок на js, который умеет сразу показывать результат, ну и кучу всего остального, до чего сейчас додумались в сфере веба. Например такой движок, как на http://ru.stackoverflow.com . Но, конкретно этот мне не нравится из-за игнорирования перехода на новую строку.

За компанию хотелось бы прояснить, движок на js будет использоваться для отображения всех сохраненных данных или только при редактировании?

Comment: Вы "написали движок википедии"(какую именно его часть?), теперь вам нужен редактор для "полного счастья"...редактор чего? И почему на JS?

Comment: Всю, начиная с сервера. Дизайн не мой.  Форма для редактирования открывается по кнопке "Править". Сейчас это просто форма с текстом, а хотелось бы, чтобы при вводе текста сразу показывалось в каком виде оно будет отображаться на странице.

Comment: А почему вам нужен именно на JS. Можно, в общем-то, поверить в то, что на плюсах "движок" плохо написали, но, блин, JS на стороне сервера - это вообще отдельная песня..

Comment: Оу, подразумевалось, что на стороне клиента. Я даже не могу ни с чем сравнить идею писать на стороне сервера на JS. Я бы и на клиенте писал на чем-нибудь другом, но ничего другого же нет. Или может уже изобрели?

Answer (score 2):

Я так пологаю вам нужен JS редактор, предлагаю использовать http://ace.c9.io/

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понимаю, вам нужен WYSIWYG-редактор.

Их много есть, например, вот такой: http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 2):

вот вам целый [список](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129262/) лучшие WYSIWYG редакторы